# jQuery Smooth Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, smooth-scrolling

I've tried to implement smooth scrolling into an index of info.  I've looked at this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9SDLw/ and I cannot get it to work.  Does it matter where the code is inserted into the HTML Document or something?

Here is my code:

JS (in head of document):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});​
</script>
```

Markup:

Link

```
<a href = "#G" rel = "" id="G" class="anchorLink">G</a><br />
```

Anchor

```
<a name = "G" id="G"><span class = "letters">G</span></a><br />
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to put it in a document.ready()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/dequku/2/)**

```
<ul id="links">
    <li><a href="#a">Go to a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#b">Go to b</a></li>
</ul>
```

and than somewhere in your document...

```
<h2 id="a">Article "a"</h2>
Lorem......
<h2 id="b">Article "b"</h2>
Lorem......
```

jQ:

```
$('#links a').click(function( e ){  
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetId = $(this).attr("href");
    var top = $(targetId).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: top }, 1500);
});
```

what the above does is to use the retrieved anchor `href` and use it as jQuery's **#**  (id) selector. Found that ID element, get it's top `offset` and finally animate the page.

Comment: if I use this method, am I going to have to come up with tons of ID's?  I wanted to implement the smooth scrolling to a list of test types, which are in alphabetical order.  How could I do this using this method?

Comment: @Ben you mean you want to have: `a_link, b_link ...` and the same time `a_content, b_content` etc, right?

Comment: Somewhat.  Basically I just have a letter "A" with some CSS.  Then on the sidebar I have an A which would correspond do that first A's anchor.  And so on and so on down through the alphabet.  So adding ID's would be a pain I think.

Comment: sure, but than you don't need to even add those `a,b,c,d...`. The important thing is that you have one-content-per-link. If that's in your case, that it's pretty easy. I can show you if you want.

Comment: That would be much appreciated @Roko  I'm pretty new to java and Jquery and it's quite frustrating to me.

Comment: @Ben, I'll post an example soon. (P.S: JAVA != Javascript)

Comment: actually was thinking I should have added the Script to it.  By no means can I even begin to learn Java.  And Thank you, very much!

Comment: exactly what I needed!  Thanks, time to put it to action!

Comment: Great! thanks. I just added the `.stop()` before the animation to prevent animations buildups: it allows you to quickly "refresh" the new lick animation action.

Comment: It scrolls smoothly when clicking one of the links, but it doesn't scroll smoothly when using the arrow keys. Would it be possible to make it scroll smoothly using the arrow keys as well?

Comment: @AndersonGreen in FF runs pretty smoothly with arrow keys

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working in Google Chrome, though. (I think smooth scrolling is the default scrolling behavior in Firefox now. This explains why it's not working in Chrome).

Comment: @AndersonGreen if you read the Question, the intended *Smoothness* it's not referenced on a scroll browser behavior, instead on clicking an element and *"scroll smoothly"* the page. In any case I think Chrome can be forced to smooth scroll also. JS of course. (return false on mousewheel scroll and apply animation on delta)

Answer (score -1):

You must wrap all your code with

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

or just

```
$(function(){ ... });
```